# Pathfinder divide in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, images, tools, pathfinder

[image]After making an image and later using divide in illustrator certain portion of the image is getting disappeared.[image: Lower portion of the image is not seen]

Comment: Divide works on areas not lines. Anyway there us a gap at lower corners. If you want to do lines then use shapebuilder

Comment: Results don't look like the Divide operation at all. You certain you didn't mistakenly click another button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer curved shape looks like it is made of multiple paths, not one single closed path. A closed path is one which is closed at the ends, forming a single path to make a completely enclosed shape.  That is probably why you are getting an unexpected result.

See [the Adobe Help page here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/artwork-essentials/paths-and-shapes.html) to help you understand the difference between closed and open paths, which is a key concept in vector image editing.

So, anyway . . .

Do it like this instead: draw the outer shape as a single closed path (use the Pen Tool). Make sure the lines you want to use to divide the shape with are overlapping.

[image]

Select all, and hit the Divide button in the Pathfinder.

Finally ungroup, and and you will get individual pieces, each one is a closed path.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)